# MATLAB is beeping without a visible reason?

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, beep

I'm calling a simple script (which uses `plsregress`, if relevant), I'm not getting any errors, and I don't think I have suppressed any warnings, all settings are default. The script runs successfully, returning all the data I asked for, plotting some things, but it bleeps every time.
How can I find the reason for this unexpected behaviour?

Thanks !

Comment: Is there a `beep` in the script? ;) Well I guess you checked that already. Have you tried simply stepping through the script to find out where that happens?

Comment: Hehe, no there is no beep. Debugging is a good idea. But I'm not very familiar with that. Is there an easier way without putting a checkpoint on each line?

Comment: Yes, go to home->editor->breakpoints->db stop if error. This will stop an complete database of MATLAB when the error occurs, so you can check things

Comment: I tried dbstop if errors, now it works smoothly (as it was before), plus, it does not beep. When I manually put checkpoints, it was beeping after leaving a very simple for loop, and also when I press "Quit debugging" button. Note that there were not an error in any of my trials. **Edit** :  I also tried dbstop if warnings, in that case, it beeps again. But MATLAB is not giving me any warning or error. And I'm quite sure there is no reason for an error, too..